# Google maps ImageMapType - what should getTileUrl return?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Google's **ImageMapType** and I'm trying to use it in order to display a custom map.

I have one jpg image of a map I'd like to display. The image proportions are not exactly 1-1 with the world...

I've read the API but I'm not sure what the **getTileUrl**(...) function should return - obviously it should return a link to the map image, but in all examples I saw the URL contained x and y coordinates as well as a zoom value. Does this mean that each tile url should have an image with a different part of the map? (meaning I need to create several images from my original map?)

Thanks for the help,

Li

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create different images, but you would probably want to, otherwise it will be the same image tiled. The x,y and z allow you to distinguish one section of the map from the other.